# Adding SSl using Rapidssl heroku DNSimple rails app

Tags: ssl, heroku, dnsimple

I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.scottw.com/heroku-ssl-and-dnsimple) and have read [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6931041/heroku-ssl-error-key-doesnt-match-pem-certificate) issues but am still getting stuck configuring my purchased ssl certificate correctly. I'm getting hung up after running the command from step 5 in the tutorial referenced above and getting a

```
!    App not found
```

error form heroku. Here is a list of domains I have setup within heroku (as an aside when I run `heroku domains` getting a no resource error as well..).

```
mydomain.herokuapp.com
mydomian.com
secure.mydomain.com
www.mydomian.com
```

And all of my cnames records with dnsimple are as follows.

`mydomian.com` points to `proxy.herokuapp.com`

`www.mydomian.com` points to `proxy.herokuapp.com`

`secure.mydomain.com` points to `proxy.herokuapp.com`

I have added the heroku ssl add on, my app name in heroku GUI is `mydomain`, and have followed steps 1-4 in the tutorial above I believe I have the ssl end correctly configured. I'm not sure what I am missing here to get the above error?

Thanks for your attention on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those in similar situation here was the issue-

After reading this post I updated my .git file with the new name I had given the app. Which is why I was receiving the strange `no resource found` error above.

After this I just followed heroku documentation starting from here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint#upload-certificates thus deviating from the blog tutorial I referenced above, and everything seems to be configured correctly.

If you're going through the same process `RapidSSL, heroku, DNSimple`. I highly recommend following the blog tutorial referenced above and picking up on the heroku documentation linked here if you're interested in getting it up and running quickly.

I hope this helps save some time for someone in the future.